# Multiple references to the same footnote with hyperref support in komacv

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, komacv

I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-inside-a-table-environment) related questions to use multiple references to the same footnote, but those suggested solutions don't work in class `komacv`. It can also be my fault.

I used `footmisc` in my MWE:

```
\documentclass[style = oldstyle]{komacv}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            footmisc
           }
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\ofoot{\pagemark/\totalpagemark}

\begin{document}

  \maketitle

  \section{Praktische Tätigkeiten}
    \subsection{Praktika}
      \cventry{x.20xx--x.20xx}{Fachpraktikum}{Siemens Aktiengesellschaft}{IC SG EA MF\footnotemark\ Berlin}{}{Vor- und Endmontage, Qualitätssicherung}
      \cventry{x.20xx--x.20xx}{Vorpraktikum}{Siemens Aktiengesellschaft}{SPE\footnotemark\ Berlin}{}{Manuelle Arbeitstechniken -- Grundlagen inkl.\ Messen, Drehen und Fräsen, Lichtbogen- und Gasschweißen}

  \clearpage

  \section{Sonstiges}
    \subsection{Computerkenntnisse}
      \cvdoubleitem{Betriebs-\ systeme}{Linux, Windows}{Programmier\-sprachen}{C, Java\footnotemark, MATLAB}
      \cvdoubleitem{Office}{2016}{Textsatz}{\LaTeX\footnotemark[3]}
      \cvdoubleitem{Sonstiges}{Simulink}{}{}

  \footnotetext[1]{Infrastructure \& Cities Smart Grid Energy Automation Manufacturing}
  \footnotetext[2]{Siemens Professional Education}
  \footnotetext{fortgeschrittene Kenntnisse}

\end{document}
```

If I click on the superscript numbers behind the words (`MF`, `SPE` and `LaTeX`), than the viewer jumps to the (physical) first page and not to the footnote on the second page. The hyperlinking don't work here.

Is there a solution?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: If you want check this:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397560/120578 . It has nothing to do with `hyperref` but we don't really know what you attend to do.

Comment: Hello @koleygr! The hyperlinking don't work here, see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are adding for example an footnote in the fourth parameter of command `\cventry`.  Command `\cventry` is defined like:

```
\providecommand*{\cventry}[7][\@afterelementsvspace]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifstrempty{#4}{}{, {\itshape#4}}%
    \ifstrempty{#5}{}{, #5}%
    \ifstrempty{#6}{}{, #6}%
    .%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{%
      \newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
        \small#7%
      \end{minipage}%
    }%
    \fi%
  }%
}
```

As you can see it uses command `\cvitem` to print the entry. The fourth paramter is part of the parameter for `\cvitem`. And see that the last parameter of `cventry` in `\cvitem` uses a `minipage` for typesetting (minipages keeps footnotes inside the minipage!).

Command `\cvitem` is defined like

```
\providecommand*{\cvitem}[3][\@afterelementsvspace]{%
  \begin{tabular}{%
      @{}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\@hintscolwidth}%
      @{\hspace{\@sepcolwidth}}p{\@maincolwidth}@{}%
    }%
    \hintstyle{#2} & {#3}%
  \end{tabular}\\[#1]%
}
```

As you can see it uses a `tabular` to print the item. Footnotes in tabular is a problem, because `tabular` handles footnotes by its own, as also `minipage` does in different ways.

Using footnotes in such a typesetted document only generates a lot of problems, the best way to handle this **is to not use footnotes inside a CV** (using class `moderncv`, `koma-cv` or simular using a lot of minipages and tables for typesetting the informations)!

For me it is a sign for a bad prepared CV if you really need footnotes inside it (I saw a lot of CVs and the good ones never contains footnotes). Better rephrase your CV then!